# How to find the coordinates of the points $ T$ and $T'$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

Referring to the accompanying figure,how to find the coordinates of the points $T$ and $T'$, where the lines $L$ and $L'$ are tangent to the circle of radius $1$ with center at the origin.
[image: Accompanying figure with more understanding]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that the radius and the tangent line form straight angles. Start by obtaining the unknown angle below, using trigonometry.

[image: Hint]